# Unable to replicate MSFT example for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I tried to replicate the example from the Microsoft webpage here. Under the SETUP section, the web directs to a [GitHub link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/azure-functions-python-create-fastapi-app/) but the link is broken and guess the correct link is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions).

I was able to perform all the instructions from the GitHub page without any trouble and deployment was successful too. But towards the end I am unable to view the output in my browser. I deployed the Azure function using visual studio code and at the end of the deployment I even received a URL from the Azure function which looked like

**https://FunctionAppName.azurewebsites.net/%7B*route%7D**

The GitHub webpage suggests that the deployed function URL would like

**http://FunctionAppName.azurewebsites.net/hello/Foo**

I tried the following links and still no success.

**https://FunctionAppName.azurewebsites.net/sample**

**https://FunctionAppName.azurewebsites.net/%7B*route%7D/sample**               \

**https://FunctionAppName.azurewebsites.net/%7B*route%7D/hello/JOHN**

When I checked the logs for the function app, I only see Http 5xx code in the logs

[image: image1]

There is no successful triggers using the URL
[image: image2].

So I am unable to replicate the example from Microsoft.

**Questions**

1. Is anyone else also having troubles using MSFT example for Azure functions?
2. Or, Does any one know if is there any changes done recently w.r.t. Azure functions so this example will not work?

Comment: what does the response body for the 500 error say?

Comment: It took a while to figure out where the message details are present. 

**Result:** _Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nest_asyncio'._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**nest_asyncio** package used in the Azure function code must be included in the requirement.txt file. After adding the same, the API is working fine with no other changes. This instruction is missing in the GitHub link!